# R predict() does not yield correct number of predictions

Tags: r

Creating a polynomial linear model from the following values:

```
y <- c(0.040, 0.073, 0.87)
x <- c(10.0, 15.0, 20.0)

poly.lm <- lm(y~poly(x,2))
```

I can't seem to get the correct number of predictions from the `predict()` function when I try to predict a number of values from a generated x sequence. In fact, what I get appears to just be the default output I would get for `predict(poly.lm)`:

```
new <- seq(0,19,1.0)
predict(poly.lm, x=new)
```

Shouldn't I be getting 20 predictions for `y` given the sequence of 20 `x` values?

Comment: `predict()` needs a data.frame. Try `predict(poly.lm, data.frame(x=new))`. Also see `?predict.lm`.

Comment: to add to the above, the `x=new` is being read as param `x` for function `predict` (which doesn't do anything here), and what you're doing is equivalent to `predict(poly.lm)`, i.e. predicting on your in-sample data

Comment: Also, if you would like to throw this in an answer, I could check this off as solved.

Comment: length(seq(0,20,1.0)) == 21

Comment: Right... thanks DWin. I'll update that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to predict y-values for new x-values not included in the original `lm` call, you need to provide a data.frame argument `newdata`. Additionally, the column name(s) of the data.frame need to match the variable names used in the model. `?predict` does not explain this, but it's slightly more clear in `?predict.lm`.

```
y <- c(0.040, 0.073, 0.87)
x <- c(10.0, 15.0, 20.0)
poly.lm <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 2))

# As DWin noted, predict() will compute fitted y-values using an lm object alone:
all.equal(predict(poly.lm), poly.lm$fitted)
# [1] TRUE

# To predict y for new x-values, make a data.frame: 
new.x <- seq(0, 20, 1.0)
new.df <- data.frame(x=new.x)
new.y <- predict(poly.lm, newdata=new.df)


# Unsolicited visualization.
par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
plot(x, y, pch=16, cex=1.6, xlim=c(0, 20), ylim=c(0, 3))
plot(new.x, new.y, col="skyblue", pch=16, cex=1.6, xlim=c(0, 20), ylim=c(0, 3))
points(x, y, cex=1.6)
```

[image]

Comment: Actually the predict function does not need a dataframe as input. It will use the original data from the model object it the newdata argument is missing.